# Flash lineStyle rounds thickness?

Tags: flash, actionscript, graphics, thickness, line-drawing

The sprite which contains all element in my game world uses the real-world meter as distance unit, it doesn't know what pixels are. I then apply a scale to this sprite to make it appear correct on screen. Currently I use 1 meter = 100 pixels, so scale = 100.

If I try to draw a line inside this sprite it appears `lineStyle(thinkness)` rounds the thickness parameter. If I specify 0.5 (50 cm) it always gets drawn with 1 pixel (1 cm). If I specify 0.6, the line becomes 100 pixels, or 1 meter, thick. So basically I can only draw lines of 1, 100, 200 etc pixels thinkness.

Anything I can do about this? Otherwise I'll have to use a smaller unit like millimeters for my world.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like the Flash player to do, split your pixels up into sub-pixels, and render the line at 0.6pixels thickness?

Comment: It should round at the very end. After all a line of 0.06 is perfectly possible if you scale the whole image by 100, because it should result in a line of 6 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thickness parameter for lineStyle should be an integer in the range 0 to 255.  This integer is the thickness of the line in points.  So sending a real value just confuses Flash.  You'll have to do the math yourself, then pass lineStyle the appropriate integer value.  With your 1 meter = 100 pixels, and a point reasonably approximated by a pixel, you'd want to multiply your thickness values in meters by 100, then convert to an integer.

Comment: I guess there's nothing else to do but that or something like it. Odd decision by Adobe though, they have no problem specifying boxes or bitmaps smaller than 1.